# Como editar o CSS de uma imagem Link feita pelo <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, react, imagem

Queria arredondar as bordas de uma imagem que ela foi feita com a tag `<a>` do HTML, mas estou totalmente perdido.

Esse foi o código que usei pra importar a imagem:

```
<a className="imagepost" href={post}>
   <img src={post.image} 
        alt={post.id} 
        maxwidth="100%" 
        width="100%" 
        height="410px" 
    />
</a>
```

O motivo de eu não arredondar por um outro programa e depois importar, é porque vou importar imagens automáticas, como vocês podem ver eu criei uma `function` pra fazer isso automático.

No `CSS` eu até tentei colocar o `border-radius`, mas não funcionou.

```
a.imagepost:link, a.imagepost:visited { 
    border-radius: 10px;
```

Comment: Convém fazer duas coisas: dizer que A é bloco, e dizer que o overflow é escondido.

Comment: Acabei de tentar, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Outra opção, coloca o border-radius: direto na imagem e não no A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria colocar uma `a img` e configurar, segue exemplo que quando não tiver nesse configuração a imagem vem normal, exemplo:

```css
a img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
</a>
<a>
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
</a>
<a>
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
</a>
<p>
  <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/100/">
</p>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, vlw, tão simples :3

Comment: @WellingtonA.Moreira então assinale como resposta da sua pergunta!